# Is $\sin^4 x-\cos^4 x = \cos2x$ or is it $-\cos2x=\cos2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A test question I received and got wrong stated that $$\sin^4x-\cos^4x = \cos2x$$ After solving the equation from lower powers of tragicomic functions it came out $$\frac{-1}{2}(\cos2x)-\frac{1}{2}(\cos2x)=-cos2x$$ which ≠ RHS. Our professor showed that it is correct by solving it as $$(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x) =(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)(1) = \cos2x$$ which works out correctly. Who is right? Here is a [Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E4x-cos%5E4x) that shows the solution I came up with to be correct.

Comment: "tragicomic"? Really?

Comment: $-\cos ax \ne \cos ax$ as $-1 \ne 1$. Your answer looks right, or the professor or problem missed a sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$

So your equation gives $$(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$$
$$=(-\cos2x)(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

So the mistake was a confusion of $\cos^2x-\sin^2x \neq \sin^2x-\cos^2x$.

The following is true: $\cos^2x-\sin^2x = \cos2x$